# Unable to Connect to External Postgres with Airflow Community Helm Chart

Tags: postgresql, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to connect to postgresql db that I created in Azure with the community driven airflow [helm chart.](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts)

I was able to get this db connected to the official airflow helm chart with no issues, but my co-worker decided he would like to use the community chart going forward.

I apologize in advance as this is a job role I have volunteered for but I am very limited in knowledge with kubernetes and databases.

I followed the external db guide [here](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/blob/main/charts/airflow/docs/faq/database/external-database.md)

the following is the snippet I added to my values.

```
postgresql:  
  enabled: false
externalDatabase:
  type: postgres
  host: database-postgres-db.postgres.database.azure.com
  port: 5432
  database: cool_db
  user: cool_user@database-postgres-db
  password: CoolPassword!1234
  # authType: scam-sha-256
  # ServerSSL:
  #   mode: verify-ca
  properties: "sslmode=enable"
```

The guide said to add the auth type and serverssl paramters, but i have tried them without as well as the official helm chart didnt require that even though "enable ssl" is ON in the resource in azure.

All privileges have been given to cool_user in the db, I can connect to that with my terminal as well. I am not very familiar with databases in general, but I followed the production guide from the airflow site [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/production-guide.html#database) to set up the database. I also did confirm database version is online with the airflow version we are using, 2.3.4.

I can install the helm chart and it runs with our custom image with the default values, when I add the external db values, no pod will start. I am unable to get any logs as they get stuck in init:0/2 and then go into a crashloopbackoff state.

Here are the "events" from the db migration pod.

```
tEvents:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  26s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned airflow/airflow-db-migrations-6f86f64cfc-gwhk6 to aks-agentpool-76305739-vmss00000a
  Normal   Pulled     17s (x2 over 25s)  kubelet            Container image "repo.azurecr.io/custom-airflow-clean:latest" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    17s (x2 over 25s)  kubelet            Created container check-db
  Normal   Started    17s (x2 over 25s)  kubelet            Started container check-db
  Warning  BackOff    11s                kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

I have tried removing everything off of the cluster and installing with helm "fresh" as well. I am added the IP range of the cluster to the postgres firewall as well (just incase but i dont think it is needed,) the resource group vnet has already been added to VNET rules. This connection was made with peerings in azure. Again, the official helm chart made on the same cluster can connect to the cool_db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mode: verify-ca
```

Putting the above under pgbouncer fixed this issue.

Comment: can you help me with the postgresql or values.yaml file I have the same issue I can install with default values but when I'm passing with above postgresql values it's not working for me. I have added the mode: verify-ca in pgbouncer section as well.